# How use the latest version mpdf with codeignator in php 7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using MPDF with codeigniter version 3.1.0 in php 7.2. 
Further i want the covert html into pdf using mpdf. but it is producing error

> Fatal error: Trait 'Mpdf\Strict' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\exitclearence\application\third_party\mpdf\Mpdf.php on
>   line 39

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

class M_pdf {

    public $param;
    public $pdf;
    function m_pdf()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
    }

    public function __construct($param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3')
    {
        $this->param =$param;
        $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand your code but May be you need something like this in context of php 7.2 with codeigniter :

```
include (APPPATH.'libraries/MPDF/mpdf.php'); //load library in function
ob_start();
$mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
    'A4',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
    '13px',     // font size - default 0
    'Arial',    // default font family,
    '5',
    '15',
    '6',
    '6',
    '9',
    '9',
    'P'
);
$html = $this->load->view('your-view',$data,true);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
ob_clean();
$pdfFileName = 'you-file-name' . '.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($pdfFileName);
die();
```